# event stop not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Condition:
I have a div cass="myDiv" inside the body.

action:

1. when i click on body. Function abc() will be called.
2. When i click on (.myDiv) it will call function xyz().

Problem:
Clicking on body working as expected.

but when i click on (.myDiv) it invokes the xyz() but it will also invokes the function abc().

i don't want abc() will be called when we click on (.myDiv).

may be we can use stop() but it is not working for me.

```
<style>
.mydiv{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#D00E11;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').click(function(e){
        alert(1);
    });
$(".myDiv").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: And where is the code ?

Comment: @^, in his computer ;)

Comment: now i have attached the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are using wrong selector.

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

**Change:**

```
$(".myDiv").click(function(e){  //Wrong $(".myDiv")
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**To:**

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(e){  //should be $(".mydiv")
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

reference **[event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)**

Comment: can you set fiddle then i will help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ynja/24/ see this in script you write $('.myDiv') change this by $('.mydiv');